# OpenGL both uniform sampler2Ds have same image

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I am having trouble sending two textures to my fragment shader via uniform sampler2Ds. My fragment shader has two uniforms but it appears that my code sends the same image to both samplers. The texture bound first seems to be automatically bound to both uniforms.

The full C++ code is below:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
GLFWwindow* display;
glfwInit();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);

display = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Game Engine", nullptr, nullptr);
glfwMakeContextCurrent(display);
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum success = glewInit();

GLint height, width;
glfwGetFramebufferSize(display, &width, &height);
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

GLuint program;
std::string vertexCode, fragmentCode;
std::ifstream vShaderFile, fShaderFile;

std::string vertexPath = "Basic.vert";
std::string fragmentPath = "Basic.frag";

vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
try
{
    vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
    fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
    std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;

    vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
    fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();

    vShaderFile.close();
    fShaderFile.close();

    vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
    fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
}
catch(std::ifstream::failure error)
{
    std::cout << "Error: Shader file not successfully read." << std::endl;
}

GLuint vertex, fragment;
GLchar infoLog[512];

const GLchar* vertShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vertShaderCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertex);

const GLchar* fragShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fragShaderCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragment);

program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(program, vertex);
glAttachShader(program, fragment);
glLinkProgram(program);

glDeleteShader(vertex);
glDeleteShader(fragment);

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint VAO, VBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                      5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                      (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

GLuint texture0, texture1;

glGenTextures(1, &texture0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("container.jpg",
    &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
    GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture0");
glUniform1i(uniform, 0);

glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
image = SOIL_load_image("awesomeface.png",
    &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
    GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
uniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture1");
glUniform1i(uniform, 1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(display))
{
    glClearColor(0.761f, 0.698f, 0.502f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(program);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glfwSwapBuffers(display);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The associated GLSL shader files are below:
The vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;


void main()
{
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, 1.0 - texCoord.y);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 400 core
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;


void main()
{
vec4 color1 = texture(texture0, TexCoord);
vec4 color2 = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
fragColor = mix(color1, color2, 0.4f);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
glUniform1i(uniform, 0);
```

This function acts on the program that is currently in use. You don't call `glUseProgram` until the render loop. So it should give you a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error and therefore does nothing.

You should either use `glProgramUniform` from GL 4.1+ (which takes the program it acts on) or call `glUseProgram` before setting the uniform value.

Answer (score 0):

In this section of your code:

> ```
> GLuint texture0, texture1;
>
> glGenTextures(1, &texture0);
> glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
> glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
> glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
> glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
> glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
> unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("container.jpg",
>     &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
>     GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
> glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
> SOIL_free_image_data(image);
> //GLint uniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture0");
> //glUniform1i(uniform, 0);
>
> glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
> glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
> glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
> glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
> glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
> glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
> image = SOIL_load_image("awesomeface.png",
>     &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
>     GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
> glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
> SOIL_free_image_data(image);
> //uniform = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture1");
> //glUniform1i(uniform, 1);
>
> //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
> //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
> //glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
> //glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
> ```

Remove the commented lines from the section above. Just load the images first;
don't worry about the uniforms yet and don't bind them here. You will need to active your shader/program first before setting any uniforms.

This section should now look like this:

```
GLuint texture0, texture1;
// Setup Texture1
glGenTextures(1, &texture0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("container.jpg",
    &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
    GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
// Setup Texture 2
glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
image = SOIL_load_image("awesomeface.png",
    &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
    GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
```

Now after you have setup your two textures and after you have freed the resources from SOIL what you will need to do next is to `use` or `activate` your shader-program.

```
glUseProgram( program );// Need to activate your shader before setting any uniforms
```

Then after that you can acquire your uniforms before your render loop:

```
// After activating the shader set your uniforms here before your
// render loop. You don't want to do this on every iteration.
glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( program, "texture1" ), 0 );
glUniform1i( glGetUniformLocation( program, "texture2" ), 1 );
```

Then within the render loop after you handle or process any time & input information and after you set the clear color and clear the color buffer is where and when you want to bind your textures.

```
while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose( display ) ) {
    // time
    ...
    // input
    ...
    // color buffer
    ...
    // Bind textures
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1 );
    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1 );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2 );

    // now render the container using the shader
    glUseProgram( program );
    glBindVertexArray( VAO );
    glDrawElements( GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0 );

    // Swap buffers

} // end loop
```

---

Also as a side note you can do this in your fragement shader:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture samplers
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main() {
    // linearly interpolate between both textures 
    FragColor = mix(texture(texture1, TexCoord), texture(texture2, TexCoord), 0.4);
}
```

This is basically the same as what you have above but is written in a single line of code and it doesn't resort to using 2 local variables. Remember fragment shaders are expensive because they run for each and every pixel or fragment for each iteration of your render loop. It looks more convoluted in what I've shown than yours but it is more efficient. Compliments of [www.learnopengl.com](https://www.learnopengl.com).